# Using the count function in SQL when when each row of the primary key are categorized?

Tags: sql

I'm using a table where they have employee names and corresponding countries of origin. I'm new to SQL so I'm trying to figure out how to list the country and number of employees whose first name starts with A.

I have this so far, but I'm getting the count for all employees I think:

```
SELECT country, count(employee_names)
FROM table1
WHERE employee LIKE 'A%'
```

How can I get only counts where employee names are pooled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT country, count(employee_names)
FROM table1
WHERE employee LIKE 'A%'
Group by country
```